# Aylien News API & Swiper - Pulling content in realtime without slider messing up

Tags: javascript, jquery, swiper.js, feed

I am currently using the Aylien News API (https://newsapi.aylien.com/docs/introduction) and Swiper.js slideshow (http://idangero.us/swiper/#.WZwPaZOGPao) to create a sliding news ticker.

The problem I have is that the slider runs through all of the divs one after the other, but when new content comes in, the slider starts jumping between divs and not running through them.

My HTML consists of 3 divs - #aylien-output, then #results, then #story all nested within each other. Each news post is contained within its own #story div which gets created as the data gets pulled in.

At the moment, my Javascript looks like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

var divListChildren = '';

$('results').find('a').each(function(index,ele){
divListChildren += ele.innerHTML + '';
})

console.log(divListChildren);
})

    function getData() {
  fetch('http://localhost:3010/test', myInit).then(function(response) {

        return response.json();
      }).then(function(res) {

    fetchedStories = res.stories.filter(
        function(story) {
                return ! fetchedStories.find (function(fetchedStory) {
                return story['id'] === fetchedStory['id'];
            });
        }
    ).concat(fetchedStories);
    res.stories.map(makeStory);
    runSlider();



  });
}

getData();

const timeOutTime = 60000;

setTimeout(function doSomething() {
  console.log('getting new stuff!');
  getData();
  setTimeout(doSomething, timeOutTime);
}, timeOu

tTime);
```

Is there any way of being able to refresh the content in realtime without the slider skipping? Or waiting for the slider to loop through the last div and wait for new content until it starts from the beginning again?

I don't want to refresh the page every time as I want it to look seamless.

Thank you!